# Poisson Distribution of Obligors

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

Assume in certain year the number of credit obligors of a bank who are at risk of
default is Poisson distributed with intensity  = 10. Each individual obligor may
actually default in that year with probability p = 0.2. Assume mutual independence of the obligors. Let X be the number of obligors that default in that year. Show that X is Poisson distributed and determine its intensity.

I am using the below formula and starting with binomial distribution and when $n->{\infty}$ then the binomial distribution converges to poisson but it is not tying up together with the problem entirely
$\mathbb{P}\left[ X=k \right]=
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}\left[X=k|N=n\right]\cdot\mathbb{P}\left[N=n\right]
$

Comment: you can put sum from n=k to infinity;  you cannot have k successes with less than k trials :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i said in the comment, it suffices to sum from $n=k$ to $\infty$. So in our summation we can make the substitution $i=n-k$ and use Taylor series expansion for exponential function.

$\mathbb{P}\left[ X=k \right]=
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}\left[X=k|N=n\right]\cdot\mathbb{P}\left[N=n\right]$

$=\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}\left[X=k|N=n\right]\cdot\mathbb{P}\left[N=n\right]$

$=\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}{n\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\cdot\frac{\lambda^ne^{-\lambda}}{n!}$

$=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{k+i\choose k}p^k(1-p)^i\cdot\frac{\lambda^{k+i}e^{-\lambda}}{(k+i)!}$

$=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{k+i\choose k}p^k(1-p)^i\frac{\lambda^{k+i}e^{-\lambda}}{(k+i)!}$

$=p^k\lambda^ke^{-\lambda}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{k+i\choose k}(1-p)^i\cdot\frac{\lambda^i}{(k+i)!}$

$=p^k\lambda^ke^{-\lambda}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{(k+i)!}{k!i!}(1-p)^i\cdot\frac{\lambda^i}{(k+i)!}$

$=\frac{(\lambda p)^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i!}(\lambda(1-p))^i$

$=\frac{(\lambda p)^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda}e^{\lambda(1-p)}$

$=\frac{(\lambda p)^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda p}$

So $X \text{~Poisson}(\lambda p)$ as expected.

In your case $\lambda=10$, $p=0.2$ so the requested intensity is $2$.

Comment: I am very thankful !! Momo